# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields - Advanced Repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, zurb-foundation, advanced-custom-fields

So I working on a wordpress site with the FoundationPress Theme and I recently upgraded ACF to the Pro version which allows for the repeater field.  So I'm trying to allow the client to add new social media accounts with the repeater.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Boh.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTq9p.jpg

Above you can see how the repeater is set up on the backend.

Header.php:

```
<div class="medium-3 columns">
  <?php
    if (have_rows('social_media')):
      while(have_rows('social_media')):the_row();

        $link = get_sub_field('social_media_link'); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
      <?php endwhile;
    endif;
  ?>
</div>
```

Nothing is outputted into the HTML.

Let me know if I left out any information

Comment: Also I should mention that this is what I'm following: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options page requires an additional value in the field code (see https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/).

```
  <div class="medium-3 columns">
  <?php
    if (have_rows('social_media', 'option')):
      while(have_rows('social_media', 'option')):the_row();

        $link = get_sub_field('social_media_link'); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
      <?php endwhile;
    endif;
  ?>
</div>
```